# How to break out of a nextAll() function

Tags: jquery

I have this function :

```
$('.trackInputHours').change(function() {
    var changeVal=$(this).val();
    $(this).closest('.trackOn').nextAll('.trackOn').find('.trackInputHours').val(function(i, v){
        if((v=='??') || (v<changeVal)) {
            return changeVal; 
        } 
    });
});
```

and I'd like to break `nextAll()` when `v==changeVal`; preserving the old values of those elements.

A a sort of `} else break`;

How can I do it?

Comment: do you mean to continue on the $(this).closest('.trackOn') stack?

Comment: So you'd like to select all of the `.trackOn` elements after `$(this).closest('.trackOn')` that don't contain a `.trackInputHours` element with a value equal to `changeVal`, which is the value of the `.trackInputHours` element that just got changed?

Comment: I mean to doesnt check the trackInputHours children elements of the next trackOn's divs

Comment: @kwichz You say you want to stop when you find an element where `v==changeVal`. So you specifically want to ignore `.trackInputHours` that come after that, even if their value is less?

Comment: Yes...also if they are less...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about just using `.each()` and use `return false` to stop the iteration.

```
$('.trackInputHours').change(function() {
    var changeVal=$(this).val();
    $(this).closest('.trackOn').nextAll('.trackOn').find('.trackInputHours').each(function(){
        var v = $(this).val();
        if((v=='??') || (v<changeVal)) {
            $(this).val(changeVal);
        } 
        if(changeVal == v){
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

**[Example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/KUDvu/)**

*enter in 5, and it changes all the `<input type="text"/>` until it hits 5*

Comment: Yeah, it works. But is strange? .each() should be applied to the current element of nextAll, not the the stack of nextAll :O

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps instead of nextAll, the [nextUntil](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) function does what you want?

Comment: But it also check condition instead elements of DOM?